# How does hive achieve count(distinct ...)?

Tags: hive

In the GenericUDAFCount.java:

```
@Description(name = "count",
value = "_FUNC_(*) - Returns the total number of retrieved rows, including "
      +        "rows containing NULL values.\n"

      + "_FUNC_(expr) - Returns the number of rows for which the supplied "
      +        "expression is non-NULL.\n"

      + "_FUNC_(DISTINCT expr[, expr...]) - Returns the number of rows for "
      +        "which the supplied expression(s) are unique and non-NULL.")
```

but I don`t see any code to deal with the 'distinct' expression.

```
public static class GenericUDAFCountEvaluator extends GenericUDAFEvaluator {
private boolean countAllColumns = false;
private LongObjectInspector partialCountAggOI;
private LongWritable result;

@Override
public ObjectInspector init(Mode m, ObjectInspector[] parameters)
throws HiveException {
  super.init(m, parameters);
  partialCountAggOI =
    PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableLongObjectInspector;
  result = new LongWritable(0);
  return PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableLongObjectInspector;
}

private GenericUDAFCountEvaluator setCountAllColumns(boolean countAllCols) {
  countAllColumns = countAllCols;
  return this;
}

/** class for storing count value. */
static class CountAgg implements AggregationBuffer {
  long value;
}

@Override
public AggregationBuffer getNewAggregationBuffer() throws HiveException {
  CountAgg buffer = new CountAgg();
  reset(buffer);
  return buffer;
}

@Override
public void reset(AggregationBuffer agg) throws HiveException {
  ((CountAgg) agg).value = 0;
}

@Override
public void iterate(AggregationBuffer agg, Object[] parameters)
  throws HiveException {
  // parameters == null means the input table/split is empty
  if (parameters == null) {
    return;
  }
  if (countAllColumns) {
    assert parameters.length == 0;
    ((CountAgg) agg).value++;
  } else {
    assert parameters.length > 0;
    boolean countThisRow = true;
    for (Object nextParam : parameters) {
      if (nextParam == null) {
        countThisRow = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (countThisRow) {
      ((CountAgg) agg).value++;
    }
  }
}

@Override
public void merge(AggregationBuffer agg, Object partial)
  throws HiveException {
  if (partial != null) {
    long p = partialCountAggOI.get(partial);
    ((CountAgg) agg).value += p;
  }
}

@Override
public Object terminate(AggregationBuffer agg) throws HiveException {
  result.set(((CountAgg) agg).value);
  return result;
}

@Override
public Object terminatePartial(AggregationBuffer agg) throws HiveException {
  return terminate(agg);
}
```

}

How does hive achieve `count(distinct ...)`? When task runs, it really cost much time.
Where is it in the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can just run SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table1, DISTINCT expression isn't a flag or option, it's evaluated independently

[This page](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hive/hive-0.7.1/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFParameterInfo.html) says:

> The actual filtering of data bound to parameter types for DISTINCT
>   implementation is handled by the framework and not the COUNT UDAF
>   implementation.

If you want drill down to source details, have a look into [hive git repository](https://github.com/apache/hive/)